# Example of Avro nullable logical type

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, nullable

I created an Avro schema which contains nullable logical type:

```
        {
            "name": "test",
            "size": 8,
            "type": [
                "null",
                {
                    "type": "int",
                    "logicalType": "date"
                }
            ],
            "default": null,
        }
```

this works fine, but the problem that I can't find an example on how should the corresponding JSON data look like when I produce into kafka topics.

for example when I produce the following records:

```
{"test":{"int":14756}}
```

I get a schema mismatching error.

where can I find an example on building the right JSON data for such schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to include the union, just try `{"test":14756}`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct in all cases.
When the type is bytes and the logical type is decimal, you get this error if you do not specify the union:
`Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected start-union. Got VALUE_STRING`